# How to get the response of servlet to the jsp with the values retained in the jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets, response

I am creating a jsp with servlet application. I have designed the welcome page as Jsp and I need to get the response of the servlet in the same page with the values in the jsp page retained. I have seen through google and I got the idea to use request.Dispatcher. But i didnt get the clear way to get Response values. **Note:"Should perform with out using javascript"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [include](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro8.html) the file, try this

`request.getRequestDispatcher("path/to/file.jsp").include(request, response);`